# QGIS 3.10.2 and SAGA on UBUNTU

Tags: qgis, saga

When I run QGIS the log messages panel shows something like this: 
`problem with SAGA installation: SAGA version non supported (found 7.4.0 required 3.2.)`. But in a ubuntu shell the command "saga_cmd" returns SAGA Version 2.3.1.
I removed and reinstalled SAGA but the problem is the same and isn't possible to use SAGA. Any idea?

Comment: I had a similar problem.  See the answer here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345121/no-saga-available-in-qgis-processing

Comment: Thanks, solved. I changed the SagaAlgorithmProvider.py file directly, by:

sudo nano /var/lib/flatpak/app/org.qgis.qgis/x86_64/stable/e91e50d2655800d4ad1fa98ec7a827703eaffb214a8820521239e8ceb9d8f7f8/files/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/SagaAlgorithmProvider.py:

then I changed the REQUIRED VERSION from 2.3. to 7.4.0