# QGIS 3.26.3 DEM Application Natural Neighbour is missing in the menu

Tags: qgis, nearest-neighbor, missing-data, neighbour

I want to create a DEM and contours for a architecture site with QGIS. Half a year ago everything worked perfectly fine. Now natural neighbour is just missing in the toolbox. I got the newest version of GIS. SAGA is also installed. I tried using IDM instead but get erorrs. So there is no bug or anything - the option natural neighbour is just missing and I don´t know why.

---

[image: Toolbox Searchbar]

Natural Neighbour not shown in the Toolbox

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345121/no-saga-available-in-qgis-processing

Comment: Avoid screenshot consisting 90% of white space

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling didn´t do the job but i found another thread with which i found a solution. You need to activate the Saga Gis in the options so they are shown in the toolbox.

[Enabling SAGA in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87065/enabling-saga-in-qgis)

Therefore this Question can be closed as solved.

Comment: Question are not "closed" when they are solved, they are "accepted". Hit the checkbox to accept your answer.